Did the Early Church practice the off-the-cuff style of prayer that is common now?
From what I have found the nature of prayer in the early church seemed to be mostly recited prayers. Prayers originating from either the psalms, early prayer books, or sometimes personal prayer books. I’ve also found that off-the-cuff prayer in front of other believers was seen as a spiritual gift. Would the type of prayer were you spend many minutes or hour(s) praying to G-d about your day, wants, emotions, etc be seen by the early church as a normal practice?

Examples in Acts indicate extempore prayer was the usual way. Jesus deliberately discourages repetition in prayer.

@NigelJ, yes. The Didache's "do not pray as the hypocrites, but as the Lord commanded in his Gospel" refers to Matthew 6:9, yet only two verses earlier Matthew 6:7 explicitly says "But when ye pray, use not vain repetitions, as the heathen do …". The NLT has it as "“When you pray, don’t babble on and on as people of other religions do. They think their prayers are answered merely by repeating their words again and again.".

The first century CE Didache directly deals with this topic. This document is the earliest written Christian catechism and is invaluable for understanding early Christian practices and beliefs.

The Didache explicitly instructs Christians to pray the Lord's Prayer three times a day:


And do not pray as the hypocrites, but as the Lord commanded in his Gospel, pray thus: "Our Father, who art in Heaven... Pray thus three times a day. Didache 8:2–3


The Didache commands specific prayers of thanksgiving to be recited during the Eucharist (Didache 9). These prayers are structured and formulaic:


And concerning the Eucharist, hold Eucharist thus: First concerning the Cup, "We give thanks to thee, our Father, for the Holy Vine of David thy servant, which, thou didst make known to us through Jesus thy servant; to thee be glory for ever..." - Didache 9:1-2


Didache also instructs Christians to give a recited thanksgiving after meals:


But after you are satisfied with food, thus give thanks: "We give thanks to thee, O Holy Father, for thy Holy Name which thou didst make to tabernacle in our hearts, and for the knowledge and faith and immortality which thou didst make known to us through Jesus thy Servant..." - Didache 10:1-2

Our best historical evidence shows that the early Christian church was highly liturgical and prayers were structured

Yes! I remember reading this, I suppose to clarify I will ask: would it be considered out of the ordinary in a personal prayer during the early church to communicate with G-d in a ‘non-memorized’ way, off the dome prayers, giving petitions to G-d more ‘from the heart’ rather than from a prayer book?

I would love to know why this answer was downvoted

Avi Avraham, It was not I who downvoted

The existence of liturgical prayers does not imply the non-existence of off-the-cuff prayers. They coexist in many Christian denominations.
